# Gradle sync error while building Firebase UI example

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, firebase, firebaseui

I'm trying to build [FirebaseUI for Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) sample app. Using latest Android studio (2.2.3) and Gradle plugin (2.2.3).

While trying to do Gradle sync I'm receiving following error:

> Error:Could not find method baseline() for arguments [/pathToMyProject/FirebaseUI-Android/library/quality/lint-baseline.xml] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.LintOptions.

Tried the usual stuff (Clean, Invalidate Cashes/Restart) but no luck. Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently sample code provided by Google doesn't work with latest stable release of Android Studio. This example compiles without problems on latest beta version of AS.